# How to use Box2D allocator?

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-leaks, box2d, box2d-iphone

There are two questions here. First if I need to create `b2BlockAllocator` before `Clone` and then delete(where?) after clone? Xcode profiling instrument doesn't show C++ leaks...

```
b2FixtureDef fixd = fix->fixture;
const b2Shape *shape = fixd.shape;
if(shape->GetType()== b2Shape::e_polygon && flip)
{
    b2PolygonShape* ps = (b2PolygonShape*)shape->Clone(new b2BlockAllocator());
    for(int i=0;i<ps->m_vertexCount;i++)
    {
        ps->m_vertices[i].x *= -1;
        ps->m_vertices[i].y *= -1;
    }

    ps->Set(&ps->m_vertices[0], ps->m_vertexCount);
    body->CreateFixture(ps, 1.0f);
...
```

In this code I take cached shape object, clone it, modify vertices, set to calculate normals and assigning it object to body. Question - is this legal?

Update:

```
-(void) addFixturesToBody:(b2Body*)body forShapeName:(NSString*)shapeName flip:(BOOL)flip
{
    BodyDef *so = [shapeObjects_ objectForKey:shapeName];
    assert(so);

    FixtureDef *fix = so->fixtures;
    while(fix)
    {
        b2FixtureDef fixd = fix->fixture;
        const b2Shape *shape = fixd.shape;
        if(shape->GetType()== b2Shape::e_polygon && flip)
        {
            b2BlockAllocator allocator;
            b2PolygonShape* ps = (b2PolygonShape*)shape->Clone(&allocator);
            for(int i=0;i<ps->m_vertexCount;i++)
            {
                ps->m_vertices[i].x *= -1;
                ps->m_vertices[i].y *= -1;
            }

            ps->Set(&ps->m_vertices[0], ps->m_vertexCount);
            body->CreateFixture(ps, 1.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"noflip...%@", shapeName);
            body->CreateFixture(&fix->fixture);
        }
        fix = fix->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do, and what the problem is? For typical use of Box2D there is no need to deal with the allocator and clone functions.

Comment: @iforce2d: sure. I have cached shapes and function to which I give body, shape id and it will create fixture for that body based on found shape. Now that function also have flip property, so whenever it's TRUE I need to create flipped fixture. So before creating fixture I take normal shape out of cache, flip and then create fixture. If no need to flip I just create fixture from cached shape. The flipping part is presented above.

Comment: If still not clear, I will post the whole function.

Comment: You can create the new fixture in the same way that you created the original, ie. using b2PolygonShape, b2FixtureDef and CreateFixture.

Comment: Also, if you need to keep the fixturedefs, shapedefs, etc., around for future use, you can certainly keep them in a container and then reuse them as needed.  Just cache them away and use them later.  The ShapeCache class used for the PhysicsEditor does this so that you can cookie cutter fixtures on bodies as needed.  It still doesn't seem like you would need to use your own block allocator for this...

Comment: @NonlinearIdeas: ShapeCache is exactly what I am using and modified, since I need to re-use cached shape and flip it before creating fixture. Instead I could have 2 shapes - normal and flipped, which is not good idea. Can I post the whole function?

Comment: Why is it not a good to keep a flipped version in the cache as well?  The memory needs are modest..it's not like you keeping thousands of shapes in there, right?  If you use a key for the shape, you can use the same key with a "-f" (or something else).  I would create this when the shapes are loaded from the file.  I had to modify the PhysicsEditor to emit the bounding hull and then modify the ShapeCache to store it and extra data on load (happy to share if you need the code).  It seems better than trying to compute too much on the fly...

Comment: @NonlinearIdeas: Because (1) I have about 120 shapes and only about 40% needs to be flipped. (2) I have to create flipped version in editor which hassle. (3) each time shape is modified by designer I have to go through Physics Editor to amend those changes. Nevertheless  I would appreciate if you can share the code you got! Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm...why just add the method to the cache to make the flipped version then.  That is to say, add a method that would create the flipped version of a shape with a new key name so that you can load it at any time?  Maybe I am not understanding the need.  I'll cook up a post on my site and put the code up there for you.

Comment: @NonlinearIdeas: Because I never know if the flipped version will ever be used, until the fixture is to be added to body. Flipping all initially in `addShapesWithFile` will make cache twice bigger, considering I may not even use them. It's all about resource usage trade-off as far as I understand. But I was just wondering if the way I tried to solve is legit.

Comment: Normal(non-flipped) I need for sure. Flipped - may or may not need.

Comment: I cooked up a quick post with the files and some info on the shape cache.  Feel free to take a look:  http://nonlinearideas.com/bounding-hulls/

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting indeed. I'm going to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reply 4 years late while trying to find a similar answer. It seems few people have gone the extra mile with Box2D.

So, you are definitely leaking since `new b2BlockAllocator` doesn't get deleted anywhere, neither by you nor by the Clone function.

Just create a local b2BlockAllocator so that it will be destroyed when out-of-scope. And that's it.

```
    b2BlockAllocator cloneHelper;
    b2PolygonShape* ps = (b2PolygonShape*)shape->Clone(&cloneHelper);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the Box2D allocator because I wouldn't be using the `b2Shape::Clone` method. Not directly. Instead, I'd do the following:

1. copy the vertices of the polygon shape to a local array,
2. modify those copies,
3. instantiate a `b2PolygonShape`,
4. invoke `Set` on the newly instantiated `b2PolygonShape` to assign it my modified vertices,
5. create a new fixture using my assigned `b2PolygonShape` on the original body by calling the body's `b2Body::CreateFixture` method, and
6. call the body's `b2Body::DestroyFixture` method to get rid of the original fixture.

The `b2BlockAllocator` class can be instantiated and used to dynamically allocate memory that in turn can be used within the lifetime of the `b2BlockAllocator` instance, but that'd be more overhead than necessary for what you're trying to do.